# Android Customize EditText on Lollipop and Upper Version

Tags: android, customization, android-5.0-lollipop

On Android 5.0 and upper version EditText has a tint of the colorAccent from the AppTheme on it's background,cursor. But I want to not apply this colorAccent by custom. Like for example I declared my Theme style like below.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">    
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/text_color_primary_inverse</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
</style>
```

All I want is colorAccent would not applicable only for the EditText. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you just define a new style

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">    
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/text_color_primary_inverse</item>
</style>
```

And then do:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"/>
```

Comment: stupid me. I really forgot about the android:theme tag. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have face same problem, and what i have done is like below,

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:singleLine="true"/>
```